# Options for Image Search API to Search Image Database and Compare Images

Tags: google-image-search

I'm looking for an API that can be integrated in a client's site. It needs to allow a user to either upload or snap a photo of a pin, and then be able to compare that photo to a database of over 100,000 pin images and return the most likely matches.

Ideally, I'd like an open source API, but I'm willing to explore commercial options as well.

Every API I've searched for emphasizes image recognition and/or tagging and that's not what we need. We just need to be able to do an image-based search of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following APIS for uploading images

1. https://gyazo.com/api/docs  - The Gyazo API can be used in a wide array of apps to upload new images, show a Gyazo user’s images, and more
2. https://developers.gettyimages.com/api/api-overview.html - Build applications using the world's most powerful imagery
3. Paid one - But very powerful for all your needs includes Automatic Image Descriptions and Captioning, Face Recognition, People and Object Detection, etc..

https://www.cloudmersive.com/image-recognition-and-processing-api

Hope it helps you in someway. Thanks

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. Again: I need something that only compares user images to images on our site in our database. It's not a general image search API. It requires no tagging. It does not require any image recognition features. It just has to compare an uploaded photo and see if there's a match in our database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. 
If you convert all images to base64 string and compare the current image base64 string to all images base64 string. And if you don't want to get all images from the database at once, you can get base64 string of same length from the database.
I hope this helps you.